# How can I say "a class in Chinese" (and not "a Chinese class")?

Tags: translation

As far as I know [汉语课](http://youdao.com/w/eng/%E6%B1%89%E8%AF%AD%E8%AF%BE) (along with [中文课](http://youdao.com/w/%E4%B8%AD%E6%96%87%E8%AF%BE)) means only "Chinese class" = "a class for learning Chinese" (and it may be in English, Chinese, or any other language).  I'm wondering how to succinctly say "a class in Chinese", where the class is not about the Chinese language, it's e.g. about computer science.

I was thinking 汉语说的课, but this sounds like the class (not the teacher) speaks Chinese, which is nonsense.  Another possibility is 用汉语的课, and [Google Translate](https://translate.google.cn/#zh-CN/en/%E7%94%A8%E6%B1%89%E8%AF%AD%E7%9A%84%E8%AF%BE) seems to like this, but putting it into [Baidu](https://www.baidu.com/s?wd=%E7%94%A8%E6%B1%89%E8%AF%AD%E7%9A%84%E8%AF%BE) gives far too few hits for it to be widely used.

It came up in a WeChat discussion, and I eventually wrote:

> 新学生需要参加ＨＳＫ４考试，因为老师用汉语教他们的课

with the intention of meaning

> New students need to sit the HSK4 exam, because the teachers use Chinese to teach their classes.

But it seems too wordy.

**Question**: How can I say "a class in Chinese" (and not "a Chinese class")?

---

This is related to my previous [question about 汉语书](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/29600/does-%E6%B1%89%E8%AF%AD%E4%B9%A6-h%C3%A0ny%C7%94-sh%C5%AB-chinese-book-only-mean-a-book-for-learning-chinese-or), but the answers there don't resolve this question.

Comment: ......因为老师用汉语讲课

Comment: If the context is right (that is, you’re comparing classes conducted in Chinese as opposed to another language), 中文/漢語電腦課 should be sufficiently clear. Otherwise, if you want to describe a curriculum as being conducted in Chinese, you can say 此課程以漢語爲敎學語言 (*this curriculum uses Chinese as the medium of instruction*).

Comment: @droooze **Please don’t write answers in comments.** It bypasses our quality measures by not having voting (both up and down) available on comments, as well as having other problems [detailed on meta](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1644/31). Comments are for clarifying and improving the question; please don’t use them for other purposes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The succinct way to express this can be: 中文授课. Put it into a sentence: 本课程用中文授课。This curriculum was taught in Chinese.

*This is a class in Chinese* can be: 这门课用中文讲述 or 这门课用中文授课.

> New students need to sit the HSK4 exam, because the teachers use Chinese to teach their classes.

It can be translated to 新学生需要参加ＨＳＫ４考试，因为老师(们)用汉语授课。**their** can be implied in this case because every body would know it's **their classes**.

Colloquially, you can replace 授课 with 教课 or 上课. So, 汉语教课 and 汉语上课 are also fit and succinct.